Smart electronics just died after accidentally disconnecting earth wire in the breaker box
Recently I've been doing some maintenance work in our workshop that required me to mess around with the wiring inside the breaker box. After I've finished the job, I've flipped the breakers back up, and then I started to hear all the inside breakers popping. I've had no idea what's going on, so I did a bit of an inspection and found out that the earth wires going into the building are loose. I've secured it again with a screwdriver and then everything seemed to be okay, except all the SMPS devices have died.
I have not elaborated further because of my current lack of time, but I have a theory, that the devices might've entered the 110 V mode, then getting 220 V fed into them which made them burn out. Another theory is that if there was any capacitor between the earth and live wire, it could cause problems too. When possible, I will disassemble one of the devices and see whether I can find some visible damage to it.
If you have any tips or past experiences regarding this topic, please let me know, because at this point I'm very confused and looking this topic up on the internet didn't bring any good answers.

Please stop what you are doing and call an electrician before someone gets hurt or a building burns down.

FYI, typical modern SMPS don't mode-switch, they're functional over a continuous range. Some older devices do, and still older devices have a fixed switch. The better question is, how did they get 220V in the first place -- also, I assume this is in the US? (Wiring is different around the world, location matters!) There are some possibilities, but they aren't looking good: see above.

If you are on a tri-phase network and you forgot to connect the neutral, then you've placed the system in a very dangerous situation as described here. As underlined by winny, better call not Saul but a professional in this field as safety is at stake.

The building is located in Europe, my concern is that a floating voltage triggered the 110V mode and then it got fried by the 220V before it could readjust again. This happened to me before, but not on all devices at once. I understand your worries about my skills, but I have a pretty reasonable knowledge of this topic. I do not encourage anyone into any similar behavior just to be clear. Thanks for your understanding.

@VerbalKint Thank you for sharing this page. This is exactly what I was looking for. I will elaborate further to see if any of the damage could be undone.

If this is what happened, neutral loss, then the 400-V rms shares between the phases if power supplies are connected to different phases (see this). If a power supply designed for a maximum of 260 V rms accidentally receives 400 V rms, it is likely that many components are fried and not only semis unfortunately.

In Europe, and in France in particular, newly-built houses are supplied by a single-phase network for a power up to 12 kVA. In your house, you thus receive one of the three phases, a neutral wire and the house is locally connected to earth. Beyond 12 kVA, you must ask for a tri-phase wiring. The situation is likely to be different in other countries of course.
When the wiring of a subdivision is made, the electricity utility tries to distribute the three phases to keep a certain balance between them so that, on average, house n°1 which absorbs power on L1 does not overly exceeds the power absorbed by house n°2 which is connected to L2 while house n°3 is supplied on L3, the third phase.
If your house is now supplied by a 3-phase network, the situation is different, especially if you power many single-phase equipment like a fridge or a TV set for instance. In this case, during the wiring of the electrical panel, the qualified technician will distribute the plugs between the 3 phases, again, to keep the system balanced and minimize the circulation of current in the main neutral wire. In this mode, the voltage between phase L and neutral is 230 V rms nominal (+6%/-10%) while between phases (L1 to L2 for instance) it is 400 V nominal. This is what I have shown in the below simulation:

The houses are supplied from a separate phase in the upper right corner while the local transformer lies in the lower left. The neutral wire runs in the bottom and will be interrupted to simulate a fault:

In the beginning, all phases absorb the same current and the system is balanced, there is no current flowing in the neutral wire. At some point, one phase absorbs more than the other and you see how the neutral now abnormally carries current but keep voltages at the same level. And then, if the neutral wire is accidentally disconnected, you can see how the phase-to-phase voltage now distributes between the loads and dangerously increases. Needless to say that a power supply designed to operate from a maximum of 260 V rms, when supplied from a 360-V rms source or even 400 V, is all internally fried with risks of fire.
I have illustrated below the situation where you see how two houses (the two loads in the above simulation) suddenly become in series and see a potential over-voltage situation in a fault condition. Neutral opening is a major failure and can happen after a routine maintenance but it is rare, fortunately.

